# Angular + Keycloak request parameter are different

Tags: angular, keycloak

I use Angular 5 and Keycloak-Angular in version 2.x.x according to this documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular

This tutorial doesnt work for me. After login when the token request comes up, angular send the client_id & cllient_secret as base64 encoded authentication header.

The keycloak server wants these nformation as part of the post form body.

How can i configure the keycloak-angular module to fit my needs?

Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the access type to public.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your token in a body of POST request. I don't think you will be able to use the module directly. It will be better if you create your own service to fetch keycloak token and store it in the service variable and then write one HTTP interceptor which will insert the token in the POST request body. Something like specified in following blog https://medium.com/@SumanthShankar/on-demand-login-with-keycloak-angular-4-5-ngrx-backend-api-bookmark-able-links-ecb065dc7993.

But in `CustomHttp` service instead of putting a token in the header, you can put in the body.

Comment: We are using the keycloak server and the "official" module. Why are these two not compatible?

Comment: I used keycloak a year ago with angular but I never sent a token in body. Keycloak always expects it in header. I thought you might be using some special configuration or interceptor at server side which needs the token in body. Unless any special circumstances you will be able to use the module provided with keycloak.

Comment: I dont want to send a token in the body. To get the auth token i have to send a post request to the keycloak server which contain e.g. clientid, secret and a previously requested code in the request body. But the angular module sends the clientid and secret in the head. I dont think, Somebody has made such a major change to the Server.

Comment: I have tried it again.
i need to provide the following in the post request body:
code
grant_type
redirect_uri
client_id
client secret
Then i get a response with a response with access token and id token in the response head.

The angular keycloak module send the client_id and the client_secred encoded in the head of the request instead.

Iam really interested in if this is because of an old server version or something and if there is a suitable module for our server.

I'm happy about your help.

Comment: Let me try it once... If I get any answer I will modify the answer... And I will add comment as well

Comment: So i just change the access_type to public, now i get a token. But after that, the keycloak tries to open .../account and sends the token in the head. This also wont work, cause the server whant to have the cookie in the head. Do you have a solution for this?